# How to replace a string in multiple files in linux command

Tags: linux, bash, file, replace, command

I need to replace a string in a lot of files in a folder, with only ssh access to the server. How can I do this?

for example i want replace all files Which contains code

```
<script src='http://cdn.adplxmd.com/adplexmedia/tags/xbanner/xbanner.js?ap=1300' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I want replace it with my name: `sultan`

I do something like this:

```
sed -i 's/<script src='http://cdn.adplxmd.com/adplexmedia/tags/xbanner/xbanner.js?ap=1300' type='text/javascript'></script>/sultan/g' *
```

but the problem i see error message in linux commands:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

How do I fix this problems?

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors:

1. the slash is used as a delimiter in your call to sed, so this ambiguity needs to be resolve
2. you're using single quotes in the search term but also to enclose the sed parameter.

You can try something like this instead:

```
sed -i "s|<script src='http://cdn.adplxmd.com/adplexmedia/tags/xbanner/xbanner.js?ap=1300' type='text/javascript'></script>|sultan|g" *
```

Comment: Escape the dots though.